# "Youtube for TV" device compatibility

Tags: applications, installation, youtube, compatibility

I have a Genesis GT-1230 tablet, running Android 4.0.3. It has an HDMI output that I can connect to my TV. My goal is to use [Youtube Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.ytremote) on my phone, paired to the the [Youtube for TV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube.googletv) app watch videos.

I already have Youtube Remote on my phone, and I can pair it with a browser on my computer. However I'd like to try it on my TV, and I got no HDMI devices other than this tablet. So my plan is to at least try Youtube for TV on this tablet and see if it suites me.

I'm trying to install the "[Youtube for TV](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube.googletv)" app but Google Play says it is incompatible. So I tried to install on other device, and sideload it to the tablet (I have done this before sucessfully). The problem is, I can't find any device compatible with it.

I have tried with Motorola MB300, MB525, Moto Spice, Moto G, Genesis GT1230, (and "emulated" Nexus 4, Galaxy S3, Nexus 7 and ASUS Transformer Pad TF300TG). None was successfull.

Comment: None of those devices is a television or set-top box. The app is designed for [Google TV](http://www.google.com/tv/). I would not expect it to work with *any* phones or tablets. Is there a reason why you're trying to install this rather than the regular [YouTube app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube)?

Comment: @eldarerathis: "The app is designed for Google TV". Where is it stated? I couldn't find a requirement list for the app. As for why / what I want, I am updating the question.

Comment: That's what "for TV" means. It's intended to signify that it's a Google TV app. You can verify this further by looking at the package name for the app (com.google.android.youtube.googletv) and the fact that the "Visit Developer's Website" link on the Play Store page takes you to http://www.google.com/tv/

Comment: @eldarerathis Well noted; I hadn't noticed this. Do I need a Google TV set-top-box or there are generic android-powered TVs that qualify?

Comment: @eldarerathis Guess you should make that an answer :)